# How to detect an invalid input by user in C?

Tags: c, input, scanf, stderr

I need to write a code where you ask the user for number between 3-69. If the input is incorrect I have to print in stderr either `"wrong input"` (if it's a letter) or `"out of range"` if it doesn't belong in the interval.

I can deal with the `"out of range"` stderr, but not the other one. When I input a letter it gets automatically transformed into some big number, which is I suppose an adress in memory or something. In that case the stderr becomes `"out of range"` and not `"wrong input"`. Is there a way to fix it?

Maybe it's wrong that I introduced the variables as int?(these are the lines in code that get the input):

```
int x, y;
scanf("%i %i",&x,&y);
```

Comment: Please post the full but minimal code that reproduces the issue. `int x, y; scanf("%i %i",&x,&y);` should be fine on its own, but of course it does not support letters so it will stop parsing there.

Comment: check the return value of [`scanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf). It will tell you how many arguments were successfully matched.

Comment: If you want to be able to input numbers and letters then ask for a string and then convert it to an integer later using atoi().

Comment: It sounds like a substantial part of the exercise is learning to parse the input.  If that's the case, don't use scanf.  In addition, scanf really doesn't work well if the input isn't as expected.  Since you are trying to handle the case of unexpected input, don't use scanf.

Answer (score 2):

> When I input a letter it gets automatically transformed into some big number, which is I suppose an adress in memory or something.

It's whatever garbage was in `x` and `y`.

`scanf("%i %i",&x,&y);` says to look for two integers. If `scanf` doesn't see two integers it will fail and it will not write anything to `x` nor `y`. Because you're not checking if `scanf` succeeded, when you read `x` and `y` they will be uninitialized; they'll contain whatever garbage was in memory at the time.

The naive approach is to first check if `scanf` succeeded. Then check if the numbers are in the right range. I'll simplify the problem to a single number for illustrative purposes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num;
    while(1) {
        if( scanf("%i ",&num) != 1 ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Please enter a number.\n");
            continue;
        }

        if( num < 3 || 69 < num ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "The number must be between 3 and 69.\n");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    printf("Your number is %i.\n", num);
}
```

But when the user enters "a" this will enter an infinite loop.

```
$ ./test
a
Please enter a number.
Please enter a number.
Please enter a number.
```

When `scanf` fails it leaves the user's input on `stdin`. The above program will read the same `a` over and over again. This is a general problem with `scanf`, it is designed for well-structured input and user input is not well-structured. See [the C FAQ for more problems with scanf](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).

Instead, read and parse separately. Read the whole line with `fgets`, parse it with `sscanf`, and if it isn't what you want read another line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num;
    char line[1024];
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {
        if( sscanf(line, "%i ",&num) != 1 ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Please enter a number.\n");
            continue;
        }

        if( num < 3 || 69 < num ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "The number must be between 3 and 69.\n");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    printf("Your number is %i.\n", num);
}
```

Comment: That was actually very very helpful. Thanks a lot!